# Can't locate 'xref' (1) error in BaKoMa Tex when including pdf-image containing LaTex

Tags: graphics, bakoma

I'm trying to include a pdf-image containing LaTex code into tex-document in BaKoMa Tex editor. When I include the pdf-image I get the following error from BaKoMa Tex:

[image]

Note that I tried the hint of the error message (i.e. open the pdf in Acrobat and save), but this did not help.

More spesifically this is what I have done:

1. I have created a svg-document using InkScape (svg is the file format of InkScape) to draw the shapes in the image etc. I have included LaTex-code as text into the svg-file and then saved my drawing as pdf with the option [pdf+LaTex export](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66972/24988). 
   [image]
2. Next I used online tex-editor [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) to combine the LaTex-code and pdf:
   [image]
3. Next I use [pdfescape](https://www.pdfescape.com/) to crop the pdf-image suitably.
4. And finally I simply include the pdf-image into my tex-document in BaKoMa Tex which results in the error shown in the first image above.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is unsupported compressed objects in BaKoMa TeX before V 11.0

In this reason, there are two ways to solve the problem:

1) Use most recent version of BaKoMa TeX, version 11.0 or later

2) Convert PDF such that to uncompress objects
which may be done by saving PDF in 1.4 compatibility mode.