# Importing images and math mode text

Tags: math-mode, graphics, pdf, import

I want to include to my document a pdf image (generated by e.g. Adobe Illustrator). Is there a way to include math mode text?
Idealy there I would like a library that would convert text in pdf $a^2+b^2=c^2$ to latex.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61274

Comment: with inkscape you can convert your pdf to a pdf which only contains an image and a tex layer which contains the text. This layer is capable of latex commands.