# Use Latex math fonts outside of Latex?

Tags: fonts, mathcal, mathbb

In Linux, I use a drawing software called `Inkscape` to draw some math illustrations.  I want to be able to use the same Latex math fonts in the drawings, in particular the `\mathbb` and `\mathcal` fonts, but I cannot locate them inside the Linux (Ubunut) directories.

Is there a way to share those fonts with other system programs?

Comment: Did you have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61274/is-there-any-way-to-type-latex-code-directly-into-the-text-boxes-inkscape for example?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I found a great solution (for `Inkscape` only):

There is a function under:

```
Extensions --> Render --> Latex.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can download the Latin Modern family of fonts in OpenType format from the GUST e-foundry (the font foundry of the Polish TeX user group).  You can then place them in your system font directory or wherever the program you're using expects them.  If the program supports it (MS Word does) you can also download the Latin Modern Math font which can be used to render formulas.

Latin Modern: http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern/index_html

Latin Modern Math: http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math/index_html