# How to use the AMSfonts of \matbb{} outside of LaTeX

Tags: fonts, lmodern, amsfonts

I have LM fonts from [gust.org.pl](https://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern/download) installed on my system, so I can access LM Roman/Sans/Mono, etc. in programs like LibreOffice Draw.

However, I cannot find a way to recreate the typical font one uses for set notation, the one with double stroke obtained with `\mathbb{N}` in LaTeX. I installed the file `msbm10.pfb` from the amsfonts package. Still no luck.

How could I achieve this? [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385994/use-latex-math-fonts-outside-of-latex) come close, but it is not what I am looking for.

#### Edit:

After installing `latinmodern-math.otf` from https://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math, and attempting what I understood from @David's answer, I got results similar to the desired, but still incorrect.

This is what I get in LibreOffice Draw after inserting the character `U+1D54A` called "mathematical double-struck capital S" with **Latin Modern Math** font:

[image: LibreOffice result for double-struck capital S]

And this is the rendering that LaTeX produces with `\mathbb{S}`:

[image: LaTeX rendering of mathbb S]

They are clearly different.

- Is `U+1D54A` the correct character?
- I also cannot find (within LibreOffice) several characters on Latin Modern Math, like double-struck P, Q, R, and others.
- The version of LM Math is `1.959`, with a glyph count of 4802.

Comment: As far as I can tell, these characters are just from different fonts. The first is from Latin Modern Math. The second is from the AMS fonts. Aren't these just different styles of the same character?

Comment: The exact style of "blackboard bold" may vary; there are a number of different fonts that may qualify.  The important features include the ability to distinguish the particular letter or digit unambiguously, and the doubling of strokes to emulate bold.

Answer (score 0):

Use latin modern math https://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math

Then use ℕℙℚℝℤ

Comment: I tried that, and typing "P" in my keyboard and I don't get the expected result. However, if I copy and paste (as plain text) the characters that you typed in this answer, I get the correct shapes. Are these characters different from normal uppercase characters?

Comment: Answering my own comment... Yes. They are. Thanks!

Comment: Upon closer inspection, I notice that I am again not getting the correct font. Please see the edition of my original question.

Comment: Is the 'incorrect' character shown in the updated question the expected output of `\mathbb{S}` when `unicode-math` is used with LuaTeX? Is that just the version of the character Latin Modern Math provides?