# Update on GUI applications for Latex/Tikz support?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pdftex

I am looking for some easy way drawing flowcharts with external GUI software and then export the reult to pgf or tikz code.

In [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972/what-gui-applications-are-there-to-assist-in-generating-graphics-for-tex) i found some hints to freeware tools. However, the post itself as many of the mentioned programms are very old (updates 8 years ago) and I was wondering if they are still state-of-the-art or if there are some better alternatives?

Some of the programms mentiond in my linked post are:

- [DIA](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Dia?action=show&redirect=Dia)
- [TikzEDT](http://www.tikzedt.org/)
- [LatexDraw](http://latexdraw.sourceforge.net/)
- [IPE](http://ipe.otfried.org/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) to create your drawings and then export to a supported format (png, pdf, eps, etc.). Inkscape even has a feature to export to latex-code though iirc this only creates a tex-file that inludes the image as is. But it does add the text via LaTeX in this cases so the font will match the rest of the document, which is nice.

See also:

- https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/LaTeX
- [Exporting from Inkscape to LaTeX - via TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151232/exporting-from-inkscape-to-latex-via-tikz)
- [Is there any way to type LaTeX code directly into the text boxes Inkscape?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61274/is-there-any-way-to-type-latex-code-directly-into-the-text-boxes-inkscape)
- [How to include SVG diagrams in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/how-to-include-svg-diagrams-in-latex)

Note also that iirc Tikz can even parse a simple subset of SVG, so if your image is simple enough, you might even feed the SVG directly into Tikz

Comment: I've been having a ton of trouble exporting to tikz from Inkscape on my latest install.  Not sure why -- it hasn't been important enough to debug

Comment: Getting "descriptor 'strip' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'" error

Comment: I never tried exporting to tikz - didn't even know that was a feature. I was more referring generally on how to get images from a UI into LaTeX. I always create my images with Inkscape, export to eps and include that into LaTeX.

Comment: tikz export is pretty nifty.  That way, you don't have to worry about font consistency.  Your figures look like they belong in your document!

Comment: Are you using [svg2tikz](https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz) for this?

Comment: I'm rrying to, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

[yED](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed) is good for flowcharts and system diagrams, and there seems to be some tikz export tool at https://github.com/bingmann/yed2tikz as well as native export tools to graphics files and pdf