# How to set the overlay in this KOMA-Script Presentation?

Tags: koma-script, overlays, presentations, pause

The following is the template which I am using for my presentation.

According to [this link,](http://www.scriptscoop2.com/t/aad95c871ec1/formatting-pause-in-koma-script-scrartcl.html) This template did not come with overlays.

And I want to set some overlays for my presentation, since it is necessary in some stages. For example, while listing the properties of a matrix one by one by giving the proof orally.

### How to set the overlay in this KOMA-Script Presentation?

### What is the alternative for \pause in this?

That is how to define \pause command or \cover and \uncover commands?

```
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % KOMA-Script Presentation
    % LaTeX Template
    % Version 1.0 (3/3/13)
    %
    % This template has been downloaded from:
    % http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
    %
    % Original Authors:
    % Marius Hofert (marius.hofert@math.ethz.ch)
    % Markus Kohm (komascript@gmx.info)
    % Described in the PracTeX Journal, 2010, No. 2
    %
    % License:
    % CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
    %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \documentclass[
    paper=128mm:96mm, % The same paper size as used in the beamer class
    fontsize=11pt, % Font size
    pagesize, % Write page size to dvi or pdf
    parskip=half-, % Paragraphs separated by half a line
    ]{scrartcl} % KOMA script (article)

    \linespread{1.12} % Increase line spacing for readability

    %------------------------------------------------
    % Colors
    \usepackage{xcolor}  % Required for custom colors
    % Define a few colors for making text stand out within the presentation
    \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{44,85,17}
    \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{34,31,217}
    \definecolor{mybrown}{RGB}{194,164,113}
    \definecolor{myred}{RGB}{255,66,56}
    % Use these colors within the presentation by enclosing text in the commands below
    \newcommand*{\mygreen}[1]{\textcolor{mygreen}{#1}}
    \newcommand*{\myblue}[1]{\textcolor{myblue}{#1}}
    \newcommand*{\mybrown}[1]{\textcolor{mybrown}{#1}}
    \newcommand*{\myred}[1]{\textcolor{myred}{#1}}
    %------------------------------------------------

    %------------------------------------------------
    % Margins
    \usepackage[ % Page margins settings
    includeheadfoot,
    top=3.5mm,
    bottom=3.5mm,
    left=5.5mm,
    right=5.5mm,
    headsep=6.5mm,
    footskip=8.5mm
    ]{geometry}
    %------------------------------------------------

    %------------------------------------------------
    % Fonts
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     % For correct hyphenation and T1 encoding
    \usepackage{lmodern} % Default font: latin modern font
    %\usepackage{fourier} % Alternative font: utopia
    %\usepackage{charter} % Alternative font: low-resolution roman font
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % Sans serif - this may need to be commented to see the alternative fonts
    %------------------------------------------------

    %------------------------------------------------
    % Various required packages
    \usepackage{amsthm} % Required for theorem environments
    \usepackage{bm} % Required for bold math symbols (used in the footer of the slides)
    \usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images in figures
    \usepackage{tikz} % Required for colored boxes
    \usepackage{booktabs} % Required for horizontal rules in tables
    \usepackage{multicol} % Required for creating multiple columns in slides
    \usepackage{lastpage} % For printing the total number of pages at the bottom of each slide
    \usepackage[english]{babel} % Document language - required for customizing section titles
    \usepackage{microtype} % Better typography
    \usepackage{tocstyle} % Required for customizing the table of contents
    %------------------------------------------------

    %------------------------------------------------
    % Slide layout configuration
    \usepackage{scrpage2} % Required for customization of the header and footer
    \pagestyle{scrheadings} % Activates the pagestyle from scrpage2 for custom headers and footers
    \clearscrheadfoot % Remove the default header and footer
    \setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\color{black}\sffamily} % Font settings for the header and footer

    % Sets vertical centering of slide contents with increased space between paragraphs/lists
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand*{\@textbottom}{\vskip \z@ \@plus 1fil}
    \newcommand*{\@texttop}{\vskip \z@ \@plus .5fil}
    \addtolength{\parskip}{\z@\@plus .25fil}
    \makeatother

    % Remove page numbers and the dots leading to them from the outline slide
    \makeatletter
    \newtocstyle[noonewithdot]{nodotnopagenumber}{\settocfeature{pagenumberbox}{\@gobble}}
    \makeatother
    \usetocstyle{nodotnopagenumber}

    \AtBeginDocument{\renewcaptionname{english}{\contentsname}{\Large Outline}} % Change the name of the table of contents
    %------------------------------------------------

    %------------------------------------------------
    % Header configuration - if you don't want a header remove this block
    \ihead{
    \hspace{-2mm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [xshift=\paperwidth/2,yshift=-\headheight] (mybar) at (current page.north west)[rectangle,fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=\paperwidth,minimum height=2\headheight,top color=mygreen!64,bottom color=mygreen]{}; % Colored bar
    \node[below of=mybar,yshift=3.3mm,rectangle,shade,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=128mm,minimum height =1.5mm,top color=black!50,bottom color=white]{}; % Shadow under the colored bar
    shadow
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \color{white}\runninghead} % Header text defined by the \runninghead command below and colored white for contrast
    %------------------------------------------------

    %------------------------------------------------
    % Footer configuration
    \newlength{\footheight}
    \setlength{\footheight}{8mm} % Height of the footer
    \addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\footnotesize} % Small font size for the footnote

    \ifoot{% Left side
    \hspace{-2mm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [xshift=\paperwidth/2,yshift=\footheight] at (current page.south west)[rectangle,fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=\paperwidth,minimum height=3pt,top color=mygreen,bottom color=mygreen]{}; % Green bar
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \myauthor\ \raisebox{0.2mm}{$\bm{\vert}$}\ \myuni % Left side text
    }

    \ofoot[\pagemark/\pageref{LastPage}\hspace{-2mm}]{\pagemark/\pageref{LastPage}\hspace{-2mm}} % Right side
    %------------------------------------------------

    %------------------------------------------------
    % Section spacing - deeper section titles are given less space due to lesser importance
    \usepackage{titlesec} % Required for customizing section spacing
    \titlespacing{\section}{0mm}{0mm}{0mm} % Lengths are: left, before, after
    \titlespacing{\subsection}{0mm}{0mm}{-1mm} % Lengths are: left, before, after
    \titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0mm}{0mm}{-2mm} % Lengths are: left, before, after
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % How deep sections are numbered, set to no numbering by default - change to 1 for numbering sections, 2 for numbering sections and subsections, etc
    %------------------------------------------------

    %------------------------------------------------
    % Theorem style
    \newtheoremstyle{mythmstyle} % Defines a new theorem style used in this template
    {0.5em} % Space above
    {0.5em} % Space below
    {} % Body font
    {} % Indent amount
    {\sffamily\bfseries} % Head font
    {} % Punctuation after head
    {\newline} % Space after head
    {\thmname{#1}\ \thmnote{(#3)}} % Head spec

    \theoremstyle{mythmstyle} % Change the default style of the theorem to the one defined above
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] % Label for theorems
    \newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark} % Label for remarks
    \newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm} % Label for algorithms
    \makeatletter % Correct qed adjustment
    %------------------------------------------------

    %------------------------------------------------
    % The code for the box which can be used to highlight an element of a slide (such as a theorem)
    \newcommand*{\mybox}[2]{ % The box takes two arguments: width and content
    \par\noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}[mynodestyle/.style={rectangle,draw=mygreen,thick,inner sep=2mm,text justified,top color=white,bottom color=white,above}]\node[mynodestyle,at={(0.5*#1+2mm+0.4pt,0)}]{ % Box formatting
    \begin{minipage}[t]{#1}
    #2
    \end{minipage}
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \par\vspace{-1.3em}}
    %------------------------------------------------

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   PRESENTATION INFORMATION
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \newcommand*{\mytitle}{Presentation Title} % Title
    \newcommand*{\runninghead}{Running Head} % Running head displayed on almost all slides
    \newcommand*{\myauthor}{John Smith} % Presenters name(s)
    \newcommand*{\mydate}{\today} % Presentation date
    \newcommand*{\myuni}{University of California --- Department of Statistics} % University or department

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \begin{document}

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   TITLE SLIDE
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    % Title slide - you may have to tweak a few of the numbers if you wish to make changes to the layout
    \thispagestyle{empty} % No slide header and footer
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] % Background box
    \node [xshift=\paperwidth/2,yshift=\paperheight/2] at (current page.south west)[rectangle,fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=\paperwidth,minimum height=\paperheight/3,top color=mygreen,bottom color=mygreen]{}; % Change the height of the box, its colors and position on the page here
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % Text within the box
    \begin{flushright}
    \vspace{0.6cm}
    \color{white}\sffamily
    {\bfseries\Large\mytitle\par} % Title
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \normalsize
    \myauthor\par % Author name
    \mydate\par % Date
    \vfill
    \end{flushright}

    \clearpage

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   TABLE OF CONTENTS
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \thispagestyle{empty} % No slide header and footer

    \small\tableofcontents % Change the font size and print the table of contents - it may be useful to shrink the font size further if the presentation is full of sections
    % To exclude sections/subsections from the table of contents, put an asterisk after \(sub)section like so: \section*{Section Name}

    \clearpage

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   PRESENTATION SLIDES
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \section{Displaying Text}

    \clearpage

    %------------------------------------------------

    \subsection{Paragraphs of Text and Formatting}

    \textit{Sed iaculis} dapibus gravida. Morbi sed tortor erat, nec interdum arcu. Sed id lorem lectus. Quisque viverra augue id sem ornare non aliquam nibh tristique. Aenean in ligula nisl. Nulla sed tellus ipsum.

    \begin{multicols}{2} % Divide text into multiple columns
    \mygreen{Sed diam enim, sagittis nec} condimentum sit amet, ullamcorper sit amet libero. \mybrown{Aliquam vel dui orci}, a porta odio. \myred{Nullam id suscipit} ipsum. \myblue{Aenean lobortis} commodo sem, ut commodo leo gravida vitae. Pellentesque vehicula ante iaculis arcu pretium rutrum eget sit amet purus. Integer ornare nulla quis neque ultrices lobortis. Vestibulum ultrices tincidunt libero, quis commodo erat ullamcorper id.
    \end{multicols}

    \clearpage

    %------------------------------------------------

    \subsection{Bullet Points and Numbered Lists}

    \begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
    \item Aliquam blandit faucibus nisi, sit amet dapibus enim tempus eu
    \end{itemize}

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Nulla commodo, erat quis gravida posuere, elit lacus lobortis est, quis porttitor odio mauris at libero
    \item Nam cursus est eget velit posuere pellentesque
    \item Vestibulum faucibus velit a augue condimentum quis convallis nulla gravida
    \end{enumerate}

    \clearpage

    %------------------------------------------------

    \subsection{Verbatim}

    How to include a theorem in this presentation:
    \begin{verbatim}
    \mybox{0.8\textwidth}{
    \begin{theorem}[Murphy (1949)]
    Anything that can go wrong, will go wrong.
    \end{theorem}
    }
    \end{verbatim}

    \clearpage

    %------------------------------------------------


    \section{Displaying Information}

    \clearpage

    %------------------------------------------------

    \subsection{Table}

    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l l l}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Treatments} & \textbf{Response 1} & \textbf{Response 2}\\
    \midrule
    Treatment 1 & 0.0003262 & 0.562 \\
    Treatment 2 & 0.0015681 & 0.910 \\
    Treatment 3 & 0.0009271 & 0.296 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Table caption}
    \end{table}

    \clearpage

    %------------------------------------------------


    \subsection{Theorem}

    The most common definition of \mygreen{Murphy's Law} is as follows.

    \mybox{0.8\textwidth}{ % Example of encapsulating text in a colored box
    \begin{theorem}[Murphy (1949)]
    Anything that can go wrong, will go wrong.
    \end{theorem}
    }

    \begin{proof}
    A special case of this theorem is proven in the textbook.
    \end{proof}

    \begin{remark}
    This is a remark.
    \end{remark}

    \begin{algorithm}
    This is an algorithm.
    \end{algorithm}

    \clearpage

    %------------------------------------------------

    \section{Citations}

    An example of the \texttt{\textbackslash cite} command to cite within the presentation:

    This statement requires citation \cite{Smith:2012qr}.

    \clearpage

    %------------------------------------------------

    \thispagestyle{empty} % No slide header and footer

    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{sample}

    \clearpage

    %------------------------------------------------

    \thispagestyle{empty} % No slide header and footer

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] % Background box
    \node [xshift=\paperwidth/2,yshift=\paperheight/2] at (current page.south west)[rectangle,fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=\paperwidth,minimum height=\paperheight/3,top color=mygreen,bottom color=mygreen]{}; % Change the height of the box, its colors and position on the page here
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % Text within the box
    \begin{flushright}
    \vspace{0.6cm}
    \color{white}\sffamily
    {\bfseries\LARGE Questions?\par} % Request for questions text
    \vfill
    \end{flushright}

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to use beamer features, why not use beamer? Looking at the layout, this should not be hard to reproduce in beamer.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230803

Comment: @samcarter I the author mentioned in the script this template is easy to copy and paste the lecture notes rather than putting it into frames...Thats why  I am prefering this template. But in some itemize and theorem I want pause..not everywhere..if I can define pause feature for this..this will be more helpful

Comment: Please do not link to sides, which stole content from here, instead http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224040/pause-in-koma-script-scrartcl/230803#230803